# four part binary search alghothm

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search-tree

binary search split an array to two part and search in them.
but my teacher ask us to find a solution for split array to four part then search in parts.

binary search:

```
   binary_search(A, target):
   lo = 1, hi = size(A)
   while lo <= hi:
      mid = lo + (hi-lo)/2
      if A[mid] == target:
         return mid            
      else if A[mid] < target: 
         lo = mid+1
      else:
         hi = mid-1
```

but I want split array to 4 part then search.
are is way?

Comment: I very think on this problem but I could not to solve!!!

Comment: First off, you are going to need 4 varibles: low, middle low, middle high, and high.

Comment: Use the math, Use the math:  `(Low + High) / 4`.  You may want to review your math skills.

Comment: I defined    ``cursor= (Low + High) / 4``    but it is difficult to solve

Comment: Is your container a tree or an array.  **Very important for searching.**

Comment: Let search_range = (Low + High) / 4.  This is **not** the cursor position, but the number of items in the range.  The cursor positions are: (Low + (0 * search_range)), (Low + (1 * search_range)), (Low + 2 * search_range) and (Low + (3 * search_range)).  I suggest you draw a number line or boxes like I did in my answer.  It really helps.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews my container is an array

Answer (score 3):

A normal binary search splits the array (container) into two pieces, usually at the midpoint:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+    
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |  
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+    
              |  
              V  
+---+---+---+---+   +---+---+---+---+    
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |   | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |  
+---+---+---+---+   +---+---+---+---+
```

Based on the midpoint value, the search key is either in the lower section (left) or the higher section (right).

If we take the same concept and split into 4 pieces, the key will be in one of the four quandrants:

```
+---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+    
| 1 | 2 |   | 3 | 4 |   | 5 | 6 |   | 7 | 8 |  
+---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
```

By comparing key to the highest quadrant slot, one can determine which quadrant the key lies in.

In a binary search, the midpoint is found by dividing the search range by 2.

In a 4 part search, the quadrants are found by dividing by four.

Try this algorithm out using pen and paper before coding.  When you develop steps that work, then code.  This is called *designing* then *coding*.  A popular development process.

Nobody should be spoon-feeding you code.  **Work it out yourself.**

**Edit 1: Search Trees**
Arrays and trees are very different with an array, you know where all the items are and you can use an index to access the elements. With a binary or search tree, you need to follow the links; as you don't know where each element is.

A divide by 4 search tree, is usually follows the principles of a B-Tree.  Instead of single nodes, you have a *page* of nodes:

```
+---------------------------+  
| Page Details              |  
+-----+---------------------+  
| key | pointer to sub-tree |  
+-----+---------------------+  
| key | pointer to sub-tree |  
+-----+---------------------+  
| key | pointer to sub-tree |  
+-----+---------------------+  
| key | pointer to sub-tree |  
+-----+---------------------+
```

The page node is an array of nodes.  Most algorithms use a binary search in the array of nodes.  When the key range is found, the algorithm then traverses the link to the appropriate sub-tree.  The process repeats until the key is found in the Page node or on a leaf node.

### What is your data structure and where lies your confusion?

Comment: Is it of any practical use?

Comment: I now that one list split to tow then split to two. but I want to split  array to 4 part in every section in tree.

Comment: Your code and example you posted is incorrect for a binary search tree.  Search the web for "c++ B-Tree".  The binary search algorithm you posted is for arrays not trees.

Comment: @v3ga: A divide by 4 search will reduce the number of ranges.  It should reduce the search time on large arrays.  See also "Fibonacci Search".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews A divide by 4 search will have half as many iterations but the no of comparisons in each iterations are doubled. It should make no difference to the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: my data structure is an array